How to change this Bedrock command to a Java command?
I have this Bedrock edition command:
/execute @e[type=item,name=Lightning] ~ ~ ~ execute @p[name=BrownCoat67] ^ ^ ^ summon lightning_bolt ^ ^1 ^7

How can I convert it to work with Java edition 1.20.4?

Welcome to Arqade! On Minecraft commands questions, please see our guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question, especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and edit in the requested information to your post.

I can't understand what you are trying to do, but this should have the right syntax at least:
/execute at @e[type=item,name=Lightning] at @p[name=BrownCoat67] run summon lightning_bolt ^ ^1 ^7


Note that you never need run execute, since run ends a sequence of execute subcommands and execute starts them again. You can also replace the as <whatever> at @s with at <whatever> in this particular command, since the current entity is never relevant.

@AjaxGb thanks, never used chained execute in my life

To be clear I meant "remove" as in "remove both the run and the execute. So /execute at @e[type=item,name=Lightning] at @p[name=BrownCoat67] run summon lightning_bolt ^ ^1 ^7

@AjaxGb fixed. Btw feel free to suggest an edit in the future if you spot errors in syntax
